# DOM Manipulation even when Browser is minimized? Chrome Extension + WebWorker API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-extension, web-worker

I'm building an Tinder auto swiper as a fun project to learn about Chrome Extension development.
One challenge I was facing is timer throttling when the tab is inactive or in background.
I tried using WebWorker API and it fixed the timer throttling but the DOM Manipulation (e.g the like button click) is still not working properly.

The main reason is because new profiles are not loading when the browser is in background.

Is there any way to force chrome to treat a minimised browser exactly the same as an maximised one?
I don't want chrome to save resources.

Comment: There's no specific API for this, so you'll have to find how the site detects being minimized and spoof it. Maybe it listens to `blur` event or `visibilitychange` event, in which case you can spoof the method that registers the event (usually document.addEventListener) in [page context](/a/9517879).

Comment: @wOxxOm so you think it could be possible? I thought that chrome slows down the whole browser window to an extend that no website works properly in the background.
I was about to give up on that.